# WillPopScope is deprecated in Flutter, What can we do Instance of WillpopScope?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

WillpopScope is deprecared after v3.12.0-1.0.pre. you can find more details thought [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) link.

So, PopScope calss we can use directly instance of WillPopScope, so you can find more details by using [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-predictive-back) link.

and I faced some issues and I fix those are so I share my isses and answers as help for others,

1.How to prevent go to back when click defult back button on mobile devices,

```
return Scaffold(
      body: PopScope(
        canPop: true,
        onPopInvoked: (didPop) {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        ),
  );
```

when I was making a game I want prevent goin to back when click the default back button, I fix it as above example.your's requirements are will be different but logic is same,

I thnink anyone can get help with this answer for solve your issues.

Comment: to disable the default back button just do this, PopScope( canPop: false, child: Scaffold(....)),

Answer (score 0):

```
       Scaffold(
          body = PopScope(
            ///
            /// [canPop] is used to determine whether the current page can be popped or not.
            ///
            canPop: false,
            ///
            ///
            /// Called after a route pop was handled.
            /// It's not possible to prevent the pop from happening at the time that this method is called; the pop has already happened. Use [canPop] to disable pops in advance.
            /// This will still be called even when the pop is canceled. A pop is canceled when the relevant [Route.popDisposition] returns false, such as when [canPop] is set to false on a [PopScope]. The didPop parameter indicates whether or not the back navigation actually happened successfully.
            ///
            ///
            onPopInvoked: (didPop) {
             if (didPop) {
                Navigator.pop(context);
             }
            },
            child: Container(),
          ),
        )
```

Comment: yes I solved it so that's why I share my experience as question and answer. and thank you your response.

Comment: @DhanushaDilshan: You should keep your question as a question, and post your answer in the answers section.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: how to use Future.delay or async in new onPopInvoked method ?

Comment: I think it's not possible now,In other words, after the popScope operation is completed, onPopInvoked is called. You cannot cancel this operation in onPopInvoked, but you can call the Future function in it if you wish.