# WillPopScope deprecation warning

Tags: flutter, deprecation-warning

i'm not a Flutter expert :(
How can i convert this my widget to avoid WillPopScope?

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {
      if (!Navigator.of(context).canPop()) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(Routes.welcome);
      } else {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      }
      return false;
    },
    child: Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      primary: true,
      appBar: _buildAppBar(),
      body: BaseWidget(child: _buildBody()),
    ),
  );
}
```

I've found one similar question here but i can't do changes myself :(

Comment: This seems clear: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-predictive-back#popscope

Answer (score 0):

WillpopScope is deprecared after v3.12.0-1.0.pre. you can find more details thought this [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html).

So, PopScope calss we can use directly instance of WillPopScope, so you can find more details by using this [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-predictive-back).

1.How to prevent go to back when click defult back button on mobile devices,

```
return Scaffold(
      body: PopScope(
        canPop: true,
        onPopInvoked: (didPop) {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        ),
  );
```

when I was making a game I want prevent goin to back when click the default back button, I fix it as above example.your's requirements are will be different but logic is same,

Find this answer by this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77709131/willpopscope-is-deprecated-in-flutter-what-can-we-do-instance-of-willpopscope) you can get more idea