Phone back button close the app instead of going to prev page in flutter
i added pop scope to my code to go to prev page when the back button on android 3-button is pressed, but instead of going to prev page, it closed the app instead. I don't want to close the app.
this is where i put my pop scope
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
      canPop: true,
      onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) async {
        if (didPop) {
          return;
        }
        Navigator.pop(context); 
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          leading: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                color: Colors.black,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              );
            },
          ),
          title: Text(
            'Pengajuan',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
//body
    );
  }`

this is how i navigate to this page
Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => pengajuanScreen(
                    id: id,
                  )),
        );

this is my home page (where i navigate) , just in case it helped. i tried adding pop scope here too. but it also didn't work.
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double boxWidth = screenWidth - 10;
String userName = (userData != null && userData!.isNotEmpty)
    ? userData![0]['nama']
    : 'Loading...';
return Scaffold(
  appBar://appbar
  ),
  body: //body

      if (index == 0) {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => homeScreen(
                    id: id,
                  )),
        );
      } else if (index == 1) {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => marketplaceScreen(
                    id: id,
                  )),
        );
      } else if (index == 2) {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => pengajuanScreen(
                    id: id,
                  )),
        );
      }
    },
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        label: 'Beranda',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.store),
        label: 'Marketplace',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
        label: 'Pengajuan',
      ),
    ],
    selectedItemColor: Colors.green,
  ),
);

}
}

try WillPopScope instead of PopScope

isn't WillPopScope deprecated already?

it didn't work, i tried this 2     return WillPopScope(
onWillPop: () async {
if (ModalRoute.of(context)?.isCurrent == true) {
return true;
} else {
return false;
}
}, and onWillPop: () async {
Navigator.pop(context);
return false;
},

I dug a bit seems it might be depreciated like you suggested, maybe this will work for you -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77709131/willpopscope-is-deprecated-in-flutter-what-can-we-do-instance-of-willpopscope

Why are you using a PopScope to enable pop? Popping the page is enabled regardless of the usage of PopScope, but that is useful when you want to disable native swipe to pop.

@easleyfixed @Bubleygum
I confirm, WillPopScope is definitively deprecated. Instead you should use PopScope()

@Bubleygum maybe you did pushReplacement instead of push while navigating to this screen.

@Aiman i use this Navigator.push(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(
builder: (context) => pengajuanScreen(
id: id,
)),
); to go to this  page

Why are you using a PopScope in your case?
PopScope is for intercepting pop and doing something before poping or cancel the pop based on your application logic.
If you just need to pop the current screen, just do a navigator.pop properly:
onPressed: () {
    Navigator.of(context).pop(context);
},

You can also verify if you are not on the first screen before poping, because if it is the case you will encounter an error and have a black screen.
onPressed: () {
    if (Navigator.of(context).canPop()) {
        Navigator.of(context).pop(context);
    }
},

I don't think it is your case, but if you need to pop to the first screen, you can use this:
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
If you really need to intercept the pop and do something with it, your example code is bad.
You set canPop property to true. Doing this, you can't stop the pop because with canPop set to true, when you enter the onPopInvoked handler, the pop is already effective. So when you issue a Navigator.pop(context); you issue a second pop. You pop twice.
In some case if you don't verify you can pop you may pop the first screen which is not recommanded!
So in your case, try like this:
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
      canPop: canPopBoolVar,  // <== set a bool var or set it to false
      onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) async {
        if (didPop) {
          return;
        }
        if (Navigator.of(context).canPop()) {
            Navigator.of(context).pop(context);
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          leading: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                color: Colors.black,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              );
            },
          ),
          title: Text(
            'Pengajuan',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
//body
    );
  }

With canPopset to false, you prevent the screen to pop and then you can handle poping manually in onPopInvoked.
In my example i replace canPop: false, by canPop: canPopBoolVar,.
It's for showing that you can control the automatic poping or not. Doing this you have two case:

canPopBoolVar = true ==> Then you arrive in onPopInvoked with didPopset to true. In this case the test if (didPop) { return;} will prevent to execute the pop twice.

canPopBoolVar = false ==> Then you arrive in onPopInvoked with didPopset to false. So in this case you don't return ans you can do whatever you want before poping.


In your case, if you don't use a boolean var for canPop, you need to set it to false. In this case you can delete the didPop because didPop will always be false and the test is in this case dead code.

I use pop scope to try to go back to prev page when the phone back button is pressed (not the app back button), right now, when i pressed it, it closed the app directly

Ok, i will update my answer as soon as possible.

Navigating to the previous page when the back button is pressed is the default behavior in a Flutter app. There's no need to implement PopScope or WillPopScope unless you want to override this default behavior.
Ensure that you're pushing the next route rather than replacing it.
Your navigation should be something like this:
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()),
  );

Learn more about Navigation in Flutter here
But still, if you wanna use the PopScope then set the canPop: false. This way it will disable the back navigation but the onPopInvoked callback is still invoked with didPop: false.
PopScope(
    canPop: false,
    onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) async {
        if (didPop) {
            return;
        }
        // Here we are poping manually
        Navigator.pop(context);
     },
     child: //your page content,
)

Read more about the PopScope here

this is how i navigate to this page Navigator.push(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(
builder: (context) => pengajuanScreen(
id: id,
)),
);  and from your explanation, i don't need to do anything to go to prev page when the android 3-button back button is pressed, is that correct?

Yes if you don't need to override the default behavior of the back button then no need to use the PopScope. By default, the previous page should be loaded when the user presses the device back button.

Share your router config to see if you have StatefulShellRoute or somelse main route to block pop out that close your app. Navigator.of(context).pop() is a good way.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Are you sure you are redirecting to this page correctly? I don't see a problem with the code you wrote.
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewScreen()));

With this code, can you redirect to the PopScope wrapped screen?

The code is not ok, with canPop set to True, the example code Pop twice which is not what @Bubleygum want.
